# Copy data with Azure Data Factory from Excel or CSV File and perform transformation on the input file

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need do copy data from Excel file with Azure Data factory (v2) and perform transformations (like splitting or adding columns) on the input Excel file before importing into my database. Is this possible?

If not, is it possible to import the data in .csv format e perform the same transformations I need with Azure Data Factory on the .csv?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Mapping Data Flows feature in ADF to do this. Use Conditional Split for splitting logic, partitioned file output for file splitting, and Derived Column to add columns.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-create

https://aka.ms/dflinks

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Mapping Data flows accepts also Excel files as source?